# How do I allocate Android Ion buffers backed by large pages?

Tags: android-source

I'm interfacing a CPU running AOSP with some DMA hardware that exchanges large buffers with our CPU at approx 4GB/s for processing.

Running my algorithm on canned data works just fine.

Profiling shows that we're spending quite a bit of time doing cache invalidation and waiting on MMU dTLB misses. I've already locked the DRAM and interconnect speed at maximum.

For compatibility with the rest of our codebase, I'd like to continue using Ion.

Is it possible, and if so, how do get Ion to grant me buffers backed by large pages(2MB on aarch64) to reduce dTLB misses?

Comment: Great question. Did you come up with anything?

Comment: I found a different way to save a enough time, but not an answer to this.